# why is this double NaN (C#)

Tags: c#

So i'm trying to code a very specific way of getting directional 2D collision and this one double keeps giving me a NaN value. None of the values it uses is NaN so it's gotta be something in this line where the value is called

```
double dX = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(collisionCorner.X - playerCorner.X, 2) + 
                      Math.Pow((collisionCorner.X - (2 * playerCorner.Y) + 
                               (thatOnePart * playerCorner.X)) / thatOnePart, 2));
```

The thatOnePart value is just a shortcut for me, it's something i need to use a lot here so that's why i made it, in case it's important i'll add it here:

```
double thatOnePart = ((newPlayerCorner.Y - playerCorner.Y) /
                      (newPlayerCorner.X - playerCorner.X));
```

**UPDATE:**

i broke it all down to seperate operations to see where it goes wrong:

```
double dx1 = collisionCorner.X - playerCorner.X;
        Console.WriteLine("dx1 operation 1: " + dx1);
        dx1 = Math.Pow(dx1, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("dx1 operation 2: " + dx1);

        double dx2 = thatOnePart / playerCorner.X;
        Console.WriteLine("dx2 operation 1: " + dx2);
        dx2 -= playerCorner.Y * 2;
        Console.WriteLine("dx2 operation 2: " + dx2);
        dx2 += collisionCorner.X;
        Console.WriteLine("dx2 operation 3: " + dx2);
        dx2 = dx2 / thatOnePart;
        Console.WriteLine("dx2 operation 4: " + dx2);
        dx2 = Math.Pow(dx2, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("dx2 operation 5: " + dx2);

        double dX = dx1 + dx2;
        Console.WriteLine("dX operation 1: " + dX);
        dX = Math.Sqrt(dX);
        Console.WriteLine("dX operation 2: " + dX);
```

the console gave me this:

dx1 operation 1: 27,1995391845703
dx1 operation 2: 739,814931852976
dx2 operation 1: 8
dx2 operation 2: 8
dx2 operation 3: 8
dx2 operation 4: NaN
dx2 operation 5: NaN
 dX operation 1: NaN
 dX operation 2: NaN

So it goes wrong when it's divided by thatOnePart, but the value of thatOnePart in this instance is 8 so i still don't know what went wrong here

UPDATE:

so i added a writeline for all the values used before all these operations so you can see what those are, the code is now:

```
Console.WriteLine("collisionCornerX = " + collisionCorner.X + " thatOnePart = " + thatOnePart + " playerCornerX = " + playerCorner.X + " playerCornerY = " + playerCorner.Y);

        double dx1 = collisionCorner.X - playerCorner.X;
        Console.WriteLine("dx1 operation 1: " + dx1);
        dx1 = Math.Pow(dx1, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("dx1 operation 2: " + dx1);

        double dx2 = thatOnePart / playerCorner.X;
        Console.WriteLine("dx2 operation 1: " + dx2);
        dx2 -= playerCorner.Y * 2;
        Console.WriteLine("dx2 operation 2: " + dx2);
        dx2 += collisionCorner.X;
        Console.WriteLine("dx2 operation 3: " + dx2);
        dx2 = dx2 / thatOnePart;
        Console.WriteLine("dx2 operation 4: " + dx2);
        Console.WriteLine("thatOnePart: " + thatOnePart);
        dx2 = Math.Pow(dx2, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("dx2 operation 5: " + dx2);

        double dX = dx1 + dx2;
        Console.WriteLine("dX operation 1: " + dX);
        dX = Math.Sqrt(dX);
        Console.WriteLine("dX operation 2: " + dX);
```

and the console gives me:

```
collisionCornerX = 224 
thatOnePart      = 8 
playerCornerX    = 193,6004 
playerCornerY    = 246,0005

dx1 operation 1: 30,3995513916016
dx1 operation 2: 924,132724810625
dx2 operation 1: 8
dx2 operation 2: 8
dx2 operation 3: 8
dx2 operation 4: NaN
    thatOnePart: 8
dx2 operation 5: NaN
 dX operation 1: NaN
 dX operation 2: NaN
```

UPDATE:

I checked the value of each parameter, this is what the console gives me, they all stay the same all throughout

```
collisionCornerX = 224 thatOnePart = -8 playerCornerX = 194,4005 
playerCornerY = 227,6004
dx1 operation 1: 29,5995483398438
collisionCornerX = 224 thatOnePart = -8 playerCornerX = 194,4005                     playerCornerY = 227,6004
dx1 operation 2: 876,133261922747
collisionCornerX = 224 thatOnePart = -8 playerCornerX = 194,4005 playerCornerY = 227,6004
dx2 operation 1: -8
collisionCornerX = 224 thatOnePart = -8 playerCornerX = 194,4005 playerCornerY = 227,6004
dx2 operation 2: -8
collisionCornerX = 224 thatOnePart = -8 playerCornerX = 194,4005 playerCornerY = 227,6004
dx2 operation 3: -8
collisionCornerX = 224 thatOnePart = -8 playerCornerX = 194,4005 playerCornerY = 227,6004
dx2 operation 4: NaN
collisionCornerX = 224 thatOnePart = -8 playerCornerX = 194,4005 playerCornerY = 227,6004
thatOnePart: -8
dx2 operation 5: NaN
collisionCornerX = 224 thatOnePart = -8 playerCornerX = 194,4005 playerCornerY = 227,6004
dX operation 1: NaN
collisionCornerX = 224 thatOnePart = -8 playerCornerX = 194,4005 playerCornerY = 227,6004
dX operation 2: NaN
collisionCornerX = 224 thatOnePart = -8 playerCornerX = 194,4005 playerCornerY = 227,6004
```

Comment: I see some division in there. Any way `thatOnePart` evaluates to zero?

Comment: dividing by 0??

Comment: If `newPlayerCorner.X` is equal to `playerCorner.X`, then by subtracting one another results in 0. In this case you make a division by 0.

Comment: Actually floating point math would result in +/- Inf on division by 0, no?

Comment: Shouldnt division by 0 result in an exception instead of NaN?

Comment: @RandRandom: no, only for integers, since integers have no way to store a `NaN`.

Comment: these are the values used one of the times that dX was equal to NaN: collisioncornerX = 224 playerCornerX = 200,0005 playerCornerY = 251,6005 thatOnePart = 8 so nothing 0 or negative here

Comment: I don't think there's an actual answer to this question, but I would provide general debugging tip @TomSemeijn: break apart your assignment into multiple statements, and put a breakpoint on each to determine the `Nan` introduction.

Comment: Since you said it wasn't actually throwing an exception at this point you could run a check to see if it is not NaN at this point, it could be getting changed somewhere else.

Comment: last comment: fwiw, 0.0 / 0.0 = NaN... could this be happening?

Comment: i broke the assignment apart and added the results to the original post

Comment: i added a console,writeline for thatOnePart after updating my post, its value is 8 here

Comment: Although you see the end result problem as Nan, there is something apparently wrong with the values before that.  dx1 operation 1 is completely inconsistent with the series of `8` values.  Something is amiss before Nan happens.  Are there other exceptions occuring, but your IDE is set to ignore / skip them?  Are compiler options set to ignore any numerical exceptions?

Comment: @TomSemeijn  what are the real input values. with the values from your comment, I get different results. Still no NAN

Comment: @MongZhu i updated the original post again so you can see the values

Comment: in the third line I get: `dx2 operation 1: 0,0413222286730813` and not 8 like you

Comment: do you have any parralel threads running? where is this code situated? might it be that the coordinates of `playerCorner` change during the computation?

Comment: @mongZhu this is all happening in a monogame gameloop, so it should be the only thread running. It's situated in a static method in a static class. The coordinates shouldn't be able to change during this because it doesn't change its position before it has gone through all this

Comment: @TomSemeijn the third line `dx2 operation 1: 8` makes only sense if `playerCorner.X` becomes `8` and the next line makes only sense if `playerCorner.Y` becomes `0`. Otherwise you results are not reproducible, and the error is somewhere else, but not in the posted code. Sorry

Comment: @TomSemeijn you should print at each step also the values of all 4 parametes that you use for the calculation, to see whether they change!

Comment: @MongZhu i did it and updated the post again, but they stayed the same all throughout

Comment: strange phenomenon, sorry, but from here on I cannot help you. no idea

Comment: Have you considered instead of using double to use decimal? Decimal should throw exception on invalid calculations (since it has no ``NaN``) maybe the error is easier to find

Answer (score 3):

If you consult the [documentation of the Sqrt method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find this:

[image]

Either you have a negative input or a NaN input as parameter into the method
Devision by 0 would result in positive infinity like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow((2.3 - (2 * 2.3) + (2.3 * 2.3)) / 0, 2));
```

looking at the [documentation of the Pow method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) it will return `NAN` if the input `(x,y)` is:

> x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity.

or

> x = -1; y = NegativeInfinity or PositiveInfinity.

or

> x or y = NaN.

so one of these cases will be it.

Comment: these are the values used one of the times that dX was equal to NaN: collisioncornerX = 224 playerCornerX = 200,0005 playerCornerY = 251,6005 thatOnePart = 8 so nothing 0 or negative here

Comment: This is a Pythagorean formula. The value passed into the `Sqrt` method is the sum of two squares - which cannot be negative.

Comment: with those values I cannot reproduce your NaN result. I get : `166,839383161667`